# Is there a way in python to count a range of rows (from the first row with data to the last row with data) from a google sheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

I am currently an intern working on a code to pull data from a google spreadsheet and create a DITA file from that data. One problem I found is that the .row_count method counts ALL the rows in a spreadsheet; I only need to count a range of rows up to (and including) the last filled row in the spreadsheet.

I tried deleting the extra rows in the spreadsheet but that is not a feasible solution to count the number of rows.

```
rowCount = sheet.row_count

paragraph = ET.SubElement(conbody, "p")
table = ET.SubElement(conbody, "table")
tgroup = ET.SubElement(table, "tgroup", attrib={"cols": 
str(rowCount)})
tbody = ET.SubElement(tgroup, "tbody")

i = 0 
while i < rowCount:
    row = ET.SubElement(tbody,"row")
    i += 1
```

When I run my while loop, I end up getting 1001 rows, when I actually need a range of rows that do not contain all of the empty rows after the last filled row. For example, I have a google sheets with data filled in the 1st, 2nd, and 4th rows, the 3rd row is empty. However, I need to count the number rows from the first filled row with data to the last row filled with data, even if rows in between are empty.

I might have to make a function with if statements but I have no idea where I would start with the google sheets api.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and the result you want? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi,  I am new to stack overflow so I am not sure exactly sure how I would share the spreadsheet with you. 

I need to count from the first row with filled data to the last row that has filled data. This result would then be used in the while loop to generate a certain number of row tags using ET.SubElement(tbody, "row"). 

I believed that .row_count would do that but it instead gives me every single row in the sheet. I need to count a range starting from the first row that has data to the last row that has data.

I hope that makes more sense. 

 @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. And also I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem from a post by @rdt0086. The solution to my problem is to get all the data and count it:

```py
rowCount = len(sheet.get_all_values()) # this is a list of list of all data and the length is equal to the number of rows including header row if it exists in data set
```

What this seems to do, is exactly what I was looking for: it counts a range of rows from the first row with filled data (the header row) to the last row with filled data.